# Spark SQL and hivecontext issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

my hive table needs to have only top 5 records. I am selecting top 5 records using hivecontext, registering as temptable, dropped hive table, recreate and inserted records from temptable. But getting no records in table finally.

```
val run_ids_for_5_min= hivecontext.sql("select distinct run_id, cast(run_id as bigint) rr from myTable order by rr desc limit 5")

run_ids_for_5_min.registerTempTable("memTBLrun_ids")

hivecontext.sql("drop table myTable")

hivecontext.sql(" create table myTable " +
      "(run_id string, SessionCount int, SampleTime timestamp,Program_ID int,Server_ID string, Service_ID int)" )

hivecontext.sql("insert into myTable " +
          " select run_id, sessionCount , SampleTime ,Program_ID ,Server_ID , Service_ID from memTBLrun_ids")
```

All code executed without error, but no records inserted into mytable. How to solve this issue.

Thanks
Hossain

Comment: Can you share the log ..

Comment: What is the point of going from Hive to Spark to Hive? Why don't you just `DROP` then `CREATE AS SELECT`?